# Filter Expression for different type of columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I use an ASPxGridView from DevExpress, named 'grid', with GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn, GridViewDataColumn and GridViewDataComboBoxColumn columns and I have a problem with filtering on these columns.
I want to filter the grid from code behind like this: (example) `grid.FilterExpression = "[Name] = 'John'";`
The problem is that the Name column is a GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn.
If the column is GridViewDataColumn the filter is applied, but if it's GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn, ComboBox or data is an 'int' the criteria isn't applied and the grid is not sorted.

What can I do? I want to be able to set grid.FilterExpression for all kind of columns and types.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the columns in your grid, try this:

```
grid.AutoFilterByColumn(grid.Columns["Columnname"], "%John");
grid.SettingsText.Title = grid.FilterExpression;
```